# C# Inserting values into database using switch case

Tags: c#

I am trying to insert values into the database using a switch case. In some cases there might be more than one value that has to be inserted for a particular case. I am unable to insert both the values corresponding to a case.

```
foreach (int thisColor in allColors)
{
    List<Subject> subjectsForThisColor = subjects.Where(x => x.Color == thisColor).ToList();
    foreach (Subject s in subjectsForThisColor)
    {
        test += s.SubjectName + " -" + s.Color + "\n";
        switch (s.Color)
        {
            case 1:
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Monday (first) values (@first)",con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("first",s.SubjectName);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                break;
            case 2:
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE  Monday set [second] = @second", con);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("second", s.SubjectName);
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                break;
            case 6:
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd6 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE  Monday set [sixth] = @sixth", con);
                cmd6.Parameters.AddWithValue("sixth", s.SubjectName);
                cmd6.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

here are the case values :

```
    C#           1
    SSM          2
    OOMD         3
    MMT          4
    Elective-1   5
    Elective-2   6
    Elective-5   6
    Elective-3   7
    Elective-4   8
    Elective-6   8
```

So when I encounter case 6, I need to insert the values `Elective -2` and also `Elective -5`. Right now I am able to insert only `Elective-5.`

Comment: You should start by using methods in your code instead of making a lot of duplicated code.

Comment: I don't understand the question, but this code is terrible. Why do you need all this duplicated code?

Comment: Of course. This happens to you because in case 6 you are not inserting, you are Updating. So, if first updates the value with `Elective -2` and after that, it updates it with `Elective -5`

Comment: @ZoharPeled I understand that there is duplicate code. I don't know how I could solve my problem with an efficient logic.

My question is: I need to insert a set of values into a table. These values are based on the color values. Suppose I encounter the color as 1, I need to insert the subject corresponding to it , ie C#. Similarly, when I encounter color 6, I need to insert/update the table with Elective-2 and Elective-5. Hope I have explained it in a better way.

Comment: @Pikoh I need to insert both the values. Not only one.

Comment: In fact, i miss a `WHERE` clause in your updates, as it is now you are updating ALL the records in your database

Comment: Prithvi, if you need to INSERT, why are you UPDATING?

Comment: @Pikoh I am doing the insert operation at the beginning (case 1). After that I just need to update the same table with the new values.

Comment: Ok,last try. In case 1 you insert a record with `C#` as Subject name, Then in case 2, you CHANGE that value to `SSM`. Then you find 2 cases 6. In the first one you CHANGE that value to `Elective-2` and in the second to `Elective-6`

Comment: I do not need to change the value from Elective-2 to Elective-5. I need both the values to be updated.
After performing the insert and update operations, I want my table to look like C# SSM OOMD MMT Elective-1, here I want both Elective 2 and Elective 5.

Comment: @Pikoh, or else, is it possible to insert Elective-5 and Elective-2 to different columns by using switch?

Comment: You need to change the SQL statement from update to insert on your case 6 then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's clean up the code a little bit and make it a little more reusable first:

```
foreach (int thisColor in allColors)
{
    List<Subject> subjectsForThisColor = subjects.Where(x => x.Color == thisColor).ToList();
    foreach (Subject s in subjectsForThisColor)
    {
        test += s.SubjectName + " -" + s.Color + "\n";
        switch (s.Color)
        {
            case 1:
                updateOneRow("Monday", "first", s.SubjectName, null);
                break;
            case 2:
                updateOneRow("Monday", "second", s.SubjectName, null);
                break;
            case 6:
                updateOneRow("Monday", "sixth", s.SubjectName, null);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

SQL Method

```
public void updateOneRow(string tableName, string columnName, string value){        
    con.Open();
    query = "SELECT count ("+columnName+") FROM "+tableName;
    SqlCommand cmd = New SqlCommand(query, con);
    Int32 count = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    if(count == 0){
        cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO " + tableName + "("+columnName+") values (@value)"),con);
    }
    else{
        query = "SELECT top 1 "+columnName+" FROM "+tableName;
        cmd = New SqlCommand(query, con);
        string dbValue = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        if (dbValue != null && dbValue != string.Empty)
            value += ";"+dbValue;
        cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE  " + tableName + " set ["+columnName+"] = @value", con);
    }
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("value",value);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

That'll help clear up your code, as to why you are getting `Elective-5`, it is because you were using an `UPDATE` SQL statement on your case 6 instead of an `INSERT`. Update will overwrite previous values that were in the table and replace all current values that match your where clause, of which you had none. So all values in the table would have been overwritten. I think you should have written `INSERT` and not `UPDATE`

[Edit]
I don't like it, but updated the code to do what you are expecting. You may need to debug it, but should give you the idea. It checks to see if a row already exists, if not it does an insert. If it does, it checks the column for a value and if one exists, adds it to the new value to insert. Then it does the update.

Hope that helps!

**Final warning**
This code won't be perfect, far from it, but I hope it will guide you in the right direction of some slightly better coding practices. Good luck!
Also this is not the best design for a database, you should really look at doing this a different way!

**[OP's CODE]**

```
case 6:
                            con.Open();
                            string query = "SELECT count (  sixth  ) FROM  Monday  ";
                            SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                            Int32 count = (Int32)cmd3.ExecuteScalar();
                            if (count == 0)
                            {
                                cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Monday (sixth) values (@value)", con);

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                query = "SELECT top 1 sixth FROM Monday";
                                cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                                string dbValue = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                                if (dbValue != null && dbValue != string.Empty)
                                {
                                    value += ";" + dbValue;
                                    //value += s.SubjectName;
                                    //cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE  Monday set [sixth] = @value", con); <-This is in the wrong place

                                }
                                cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE  Monday set [sixth] = @value", con);//Should be here
                            }
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("value",value);
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            con.Close();
                            break;
```

After making the necessary changes and executing it, I am getting the following error.

```
The parameterized query '(@value nvarchar(4000))INSERT INTO Monday (sixth) values (@value' expects the parameter '@value', which was not supplied.
```

Comment: Just noticed you use insert statement on one case and update on another, updating

Comment: I don't want to use a second insert statement because at the beginning the values are null and I just want to update the null values. I also don't want to use multiple statements because for a future operation I need only a single row of data from the table.

Comment: I basically want to know how to insert the subjectNames if I encounter more than one for a case (as seen is case 6 and case 8) into the database.

Comment: So you want a single row in the table but you want to have specific values appear multiple times? I feel you're making the table in a bit of a bad way here

Comment: What will you do if you have 3 values you need to insert? You can't programatically increase the column number, do you want them to be separated by commas in the same cell? Why do you only want one row in this table? In your first statement, if you re-run this code multiple times, you'll get more than one row

Comment: I feel you need to go back and evaluate exactly what your expected inputs and outputs are as they aren't very clear or are not being done in a nice way as most developers and database people would do.

Comment: No, I don't want any values to appear multiple times. Let me describe the table. table_name = Monday, columns are first, second, third... sixth.
At first the values are Null. And using the switch case i am inserting into the table. So the final output must be, first=C#, second=SSM, third=OOMD .... sixth=Elective-2,Elective-2.

Note:This code will be run only once in order to ensure that only one row is created.

Comment: That's fantastic, but you have a cell with a value already inside of it, what do you want to do in that case, are you adding it the end of the text in the current row?

Comment: Yes, you are right. if there is a value already in a cell, I want to add alongside it.

Comment: How are you separating it? Should it appear as Elective-2Elective-5 or would you want something in between like a semi colon or comma?

Comment: Yes, I would like to separate it with a slash or a comma or anything which is possible.

Comment: I'll update, but I'll warn again, this is a terrible design pattern!

Comment: Is there a better way I could achieve this? I don't know a better way with which I could do the same.

Comment: You should be inserting it as a separate line on the database, having different rows for different possible values would be better. It's either that or having it as a 2nd table with a one to many relationship

Comment: I agree, I am using the tables for generating a time-table for my class. Because of that I want both the values it, Elective-2 and Elective-6 to be inserted/updated using switch. Like I requested earlier, I basically don't know how to update my table when there is more than one subject name for a single case.

Comment: I executed the code but I received an error. I have edited the post in order to show the changes I made.

Comment: Moved the `cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE  Monday set [sixth] = @value", con);` outside the if statement, it shouldn't have been inside

Answer (score -3):

I would use a stored procedure with optional parameters.

Comment: Could you please explain with an example because I have not used stored procedure?

Comment: This would have been better as a comment than an answer

Comment: @Thorarins, is there a way to achieve this using the current logic?

Comment: @Hexadron, you could be more helpful and provide some code samples and explain why a stored proc helps solving the problem.